# How to tell if its possible to build a graph based on given info.

Tags: graph-theory

For each of the lists below either draw an connected, undirected graph with eight nodes having one node of each degree listed or give a convincing argument why it is impossible.

1)7,7,3,3,3,3,3,1

2)7, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2

3)6, 5, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2

4)6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5, 4, 1

After looking at all 4 i see that i can draw the first two but the 3 and 4 cant be done. is there a way to tell if we can construct a graph based of this information without trying to draw it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Degree list $(3)$ has five vertices of odd degree; do you know why that’s impossible?

There is a graph with degree list $(4)$. Let the vertices be labelled $1,2,\ldots,8$. The graph has the following adjacency matrix:

$$\begin{array}{cc}
&\begin{array}{c}1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8\end{array}\\
\begin{array}{c}
1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6\\7\\8\end{array}&
\begin{bmatrix}
0&1&1&1&1&1&1&0\\
1&0&1&1&1&1&1&0\\
1&1&0&1&1&1&1&0\\
1&1&1&0&1&1&1&0\\
1&1&1&1&0&1&0&1\\
1&1&1&1&1&0&0&0\\
1&1&1&1&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{array}$$

Vertices $1,2,3,4$, and $5$ have degree $6$, vertex $6$ has degree $5$, vertex $7$ has degree $4$, and vertex $8$ has degree $1$.

Here’s how I discovered this graph. If in fact the degree sequence were impossible, the vertex of degree $1$ was likely to be a sticking point, since there are so many vertices of relatively large degree. If we remove it, we’re left with $7$ vertices, of which at least $4$ have degree $6$. That means that every one of the remaining vertices must have degree at least $4$, so depending on which vertex was adjacent to the vertex of degree $1$, we could conceivably have either degree sequence $6,6,6,6,6,4,4$ or degree sequence $6,6,6,6,5,5,4$.

I started sketching a graph with vertices $1,2,\ldots,7$, giving vertices $1,2,3$, and $4$ degree $6$. At that point vertices $5,6$, and $7$ had degree $4$. One of those would have to be the vertex of degree $4$ in the original graph; I made it vertex $7$. One of vertices $5$ and $6$ had to be the one adjacent to the vertex of degree $1$ in the original graph; I made it vertex $5$, and I made that degree $1$ vertex number $8$. And at that point it was clear that be adding an edge between vertices $5$ and $6$ I’d have a graph with the right degree sequence.

Answer (score 0):

3) The sum of the degrees of all the nodes is twice the number of edges, so it cannot be odd.

4) This should be possible. Note that the graph is not required to be simple.